# Getting an llvm::Function Static Address

Tags: c++, c, llvm, static-analysis, llvm-ir

Is there a way to get the static address of a function pointed by `llvm::Function` object in a C code using the LLVM IR API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `llvm::Function*` is a subclass of `llvm::Value*` you can just treat as an `llvm::Value*` and LLVM will substitute the correct address.

[llvm::Function Documentation](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Function.html)